# VB.NET Pulling txt file contents from webpage to listbox (No file download)

Tags: vb.net, listbox, webclient, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to pull the contents of a TXT file from a webpage and display the contents in a ListBox.  I would highly prefer NOT to need to programmatically download the TXT file. Currently the file is multi-line, but can be converted to CSV if it makes the code smaller.

What I've tried:

```
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("http://webpage.com/list.txt"))
```

&

```
Dim MasterClient As WebClient = New WebClient()
Dim MasterStreamer As StreamReader = New StreamReader(MasterClient.OpenRead("http://webpage.com/list.txt"))
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(MasterStreamer)
```

Both don't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [HttpClient.GetStringAsync Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getstringasync) to do this:

```
Dim result As String = Await New HttpClient().GetStringAsync("http://webpage.com/list.txt")
```

Adding the content of `result` to your ListBox depends on how the text file is formatted and encoded. I used [example.txt](https://example-files.online-convert.com/document/txt/example.txt) to test and [vbLf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.constants.vblf) as the separator (depending on your file's encoding, vbCrLf might work) to create an array of all the lines (using [Strings.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split)) in the file. Then, I used this array with [ListBox.Items](https://ListBox.Items)'s [AddRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.addrange) method:

```
Dim result As String = Await New HttpClient().GetStringAsync("https://example-files.online-convert.com/document/txt/example.txt")
Dim lines As String() = Split(result, vbLf)
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(lines)
```